# How to compute intersection of nodes in Parallel in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on big datasets and to decrease execution time i need to use parallel processing in python to compute intersection of two nodes in a graph. I use the below code to compute intersection for all N nodes in my dataset. `nodes_neighbors` is neighboring set of a node which consists of several nodes.

```
for i in range(N):
    CN_sum = 0
    d = {}


        for neighbor in nodes_neighbors[i]:

            intersect = len(list(set(nodes_neighbors[i]) & set(nodes_neighbors[neighbor])))

            CN_sum = CN_sum + (intersect)


        node_importance.append(([i, CN_sum]))
```

I wonder how can i turn it to run in parallel to save time. I tried some method such as creating Pool() and multiprocessing but since i am a little bit new in python, so i was not able to make it!!

Comment: You can make your code a lot faster by storing sets rather than whatever collections you currently have in `nodes_neighbors`, and then `intersect = sum(1 for c in nodes_neigbors[i] if c in nodes_neighbors[neighbor])`. You're currently building 2 sets and a list in every iteration.

Comment: It may be still faster to not use sets but instead sorted lists, and count the intersection using a merge-sort type approach.